# Injecting List into Select By Attribute SQL Statement

Tags: arcpy

I have a list of the form

```
OIDList = ['OID_1', 'OID_2', 'OID_3', ...]
```

I am attemping to 'inject' the list (in an admittedly brute forced manner) into a SQL statement, to use as a where clause of a Select Layer By Attribute.

The SQL statement would have the form

```
'"[Field]" IN {0}'.format(OIDList)
```

As some of you can imagine, this is throwing an error for an Invalid Expression.

Here are the solutions already attempted:

1. Cast `OIDList` as `tuple(OIDList)`
2. Loop through `OIDList`  and add each OID to selection - this has proven far too inefficent, there are anywhere from 150-500 OID in the list depending when it is being run.

Is this possible in the desired way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```py
import arcpy
oidlist = [2,3]
layer = "Sites"
sQuery = "OBJECTID IN " + str(tuple(oidlist))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer,"NEW_SELECTION",sQuery)
```

I ran this directly in ArcMap with a layer loaded called Sites, which is a File Geodatabase feature class.

Comment: When dealing with OID there is much faster way of selection (since 10.5 version) layer.SetSelectionSet(list). Less code as well. It also works for [2]. With tuple thing you have to use [2,-1] +1 btw nice to see you using it.

Comment: There's also `','.join([str(i) for i in oidlist])` for integer OIDs -- string lists are just a simple `"','".join(oidlist)` (for unquoted terms)